# Read search query from a databse while typing on an input field in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to input search values from a database while typing on an input field. similar to some hotel search website where you search for a city and it displays auto suggestions while the user is typing. Can anyone point me to some useful examples I can work with in VB.net? 
Thanks

I know how to query a table in a database and display the results on a page using repeater in vb.net

Comment: read for example this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243368/AutoComplete-Textbox-3 .. you need to have autosugestion words have in a list and then your field property called AutoCompleteSource mapped to that list

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: If you want some fancy functionality, you are most likely going to have to pay for it.  I've implemented Algolia (https://www.algolia.com/) and Nextopia (https://www.nextopia.com/) for different clients. Both very, very powerful, but obviously the better the product the more the cost.  You can find free libraries out there, but they are limited to other services where you upload your Feed data to them and let their algorithms handle the processing.

Comment: Peter Ksenak: I tried that example of AutoCompleteSource and it works as expected, however the page tend to freeze and the scripts stops. Anyway to prevent this from happening? thanks